# No access to outside from some VM instances

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines

I have launched few vm instances based on ubintu 21.10 image. all of them in 10.1.253.0/24 subnet. Region asia-southeast1.

An instance with ip 10.1.253.221 has no problem zone c. I made sudo apt update and insalled softs as I need.

But instances with ip 10.1.253.222 zone b and with ip 10.1.253.221 zone a cannot install packges even cannit sudo apt update. Stucks with:

```
adm@host221:~$ sudo apt update
0% [Connecting to asia-east2.gce.archive.ubuntu.com (35.201.193.163)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.39)]
```

`ping 10.1.253.221` runs. but ping to outside does not.
Seems to be problem with access to outside/internet

I installed one instance in asia-southeast1-b but have the same issue.
There no any ingress or egress deny for the network

Comment: this is avout VMs in Google Cloud

Answer (score 0):

The blockage may be from internal machine level or external aws network level.
So need to check at individual levels.

For system level, first disable firewall and check whether it working.
Check this [link](https://technowikis.com/41078/enable-or-disable-ubuntu-21-04-firewall) for steps.

If it works then check enable firewall back and add the related firewall settings.

Second, if it is with network configuration inside machine, so check the nslookup and tracert command outputs to see where exactly the network is stopped.

At AWS level, check [these](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-connect-internet-gateway/) options once.